# Song of Rest Healing during Short Rests?

Tags: dnd-5e, bard, errata

Just downloaded the Errata PDF and right off the bat I read this update to the Bard's Song of Rest:

> Song of Rest (p. 54). A creature regains
>   the extra hit points only if it spends one or
>   more Hit Dice at the end of the short rest.

Does this mean the players spend all intended hit dice for healing and *then* benefit from song of rest? Or, can everyone spend 1 hit die to heal, benefit from Song of rest and then spend more hit dice as needed, there by not wasting the song of rest's effectiveness?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Does this mean the players spend all intended hit dice for healing and then benefit from song of rest? [...]

I believe you are looking at this the wrong way and, thereby, make the feature more unwieldy then it is. At the end of a short rest you can recover hit points by spending Hit Dice. I quote from *Short Rest* on page 186 of the PHB:

> [...] A character can spend one or more Hit Dice at the end of a short rest, up to the character’s maximum number of Hit Dice [...]. The player can decide to spend an additional Hit Die after each roll. [...]

The *Song of Rest* specifies that (errata worked into original text in square brackets):

> [...] If you or any friendly creatures [...] regain hit points at the end of
>   the short rest, each of those creatures regains an extra 1d6 hit points [if it spend one or more Hit Dice].

Neither of these statements specifies that you regain the hit points all together after all your rolls have finished. Look at it as deciding how much resting, eating, bandaging, etc, you want to do during that hour and then doing it. The rolls at the end are simply the mechanical rewards.

Hence, when you regain hit points from the roll of your first Hit Dice, add the benefits from the *Song of Rest* if they apply. The player can then decide to spend additional Hit Dice if they should need more hit points.

**TL;DR**: No. Yes.

Answer (score 3):

During a short rest, hit dice are only ever spent at the end. The Song is first, then the healing from rest and hit dice, then the Song applies to those who healed with hit dice.

The point of the errata is that the hitpoints gained at the end of the rest must have (at least in part) come from *resting* (and hence a hit die), as opposed to healing via spell or somesuch. As originally printed, you could benefit from Song of Rest even if you didn't actually *rest*, so long as you received 1 hp of healing somehow else.

Comment: i get you have to spend at least one hit die, but the question is can i spend 1 hit die, calculate the healing including song of rest, then spend more hit dice if i need to  to reach full HP, or do I lose out on using more hit dice if i decide to apply the song of rest healing after spending only 1 hit die

Comment: @MC_Hambone The errata doesn't change any text in the Song and doesn't change how resting healing works: the Song's effect waits for you to do your end-of-rest healing, and only checks to see if it triggers after you're done. So heal all the HD you want first, then get the Song's bonus. This is mostly useful when you're running low on HD.